# Laravel NotFoundHttpException on route

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have been struggling with something very simple here nevertheless the vagueness around Laravel's routing system that complicates its easy routing approach. I have gone through questions listed here but nothing seems to help me so here it goes.

I have formerly defined a route to my controller on an action named "create". This action is suppose to accept a post data from the form and persist it. This create method has one parameter which defaults to null for a project id if its add else we pass an id e.g domain/projects/add/22 to edit and domain/projects/add to create a new one.

Below is the skeleton of the function:

```
public function create( $id = null ){ ... }
```

I then defined a route for this which is:

```
Route::post( 'projects/add', 'ProjectsController@create' );
```

Inside my form I have   {{ Form::open(array('url' => 'projects/add', 'method' => 'post')) }} .

I keep on getting errors related to routing, Http or method not found exceptions. I tried to follow every suggestion on the net but cannot for the life of me find my way.

Please help me point to the right direction, thanks.

Comment: please provide the HTML code that your form helper generates.

Comment: @MichaelColeman Herewith is the beginning of the form generated by blade <code><form method="POST" action="http://tracker.ogilvyone.co.za/projects/add" accept-charset="UTF-8"></code>. I have ommitted the rest of the form as I feel its irrelevant. Plese let me know if that is not the case.

Comment: I suppose the route is colliding with another one. Can you please add all the routes to your question?

Answer (score 0):

try with below sample code

**routs.php►**

```
Route::post('projects/add/{id?}',array('as'=>'project_create','uses'=>'ProjectsController@create'));
```

**ProjectsController.php►**

```
class ProjectsController extends BaseController{

 public function create( $id = null ){
 ... 
 }
```

**projects.blade.php►**  (for used blade templating your views should have blade.php extention )

```
<html>....
<form action="{{ route('project_create') }}"method="post">
    ....
</form>
</html>
```

Comment: Why name the route and then not use it: `{{ route('project_create') }}`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for all your responses. After being swamped with work I finally came back to my project and wanted to try out some of your suggestions but I failed.

I did find a tutorial that I tried to follow and basically was able to have my routes working.

Inside the routes I added (see below):

```
Route::get('/projects/list', [
  'as' => 'post.list', 
  'uses' => 'ProjectsController@listProjects'
]);
```

Inside my controller I just created a function that is named listProjects(). As for getting my form displayed I followed the same pattern except point to newProject() method in my controller.

As much as I was not keen on this approach I ended up creating another function just for saving my POSTed form data after a new project form has been filled out and submitted. I still used the same url as projects/add except pointing it to a different function in may controller named saveProject().

About the view I just added the as part of the same save route and it worked. below is a link to the tutorial I followed and taking a look at the code.

http://www.codeheaps.com/php-programming/creating-blog-using-laravel-4-part-1/